# Clearing vue-google-autocomplete component input-field after a function is called in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have google place-autocomplete in my vue.js app.

```
          <vue-google-autocomplete
          ref="inputField"
          id="map"
          class="form-control mr-sm-2"
          placeholder="Search"
          v-on:placechanged="getAddressData"
          country="fr"
          types="establishment"          
          ></vue-google-autocomplete>
```

I assigned a `ref="inputField"` to it and when my function `getAddressData()` is called, it runs

```
this.$refs.inputField.clear();
```

But my inputField doesn't clear, I also tried:

```
this.$refs.inputField = ''
```

and

```
this.$refs.inputField = null
```

This is my gatAdressData():

```
getAddressData(addressData, placeResultData) {
      this.placeResultData = placeResultData;
      this.addressData = addressData;                
      this.$router.push({ name: "rest_reviews", 
                params: { maps: this.placeResultData.place_id,})                             
      this.$refs.inputField.clear();
```

With no luck either. What is the proper way to clear my inputField?

Comment: Please add it as an answer so I can vote for it and others can see it.

Comment: Added an answer. Thanks alot.

Comment: There is an [exposed `update` function](https://github.com/olefirenko/vue-google-autocomplete#updatevalue) to change the user input, I suggest using that instead of changing the input manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `refs` like this

```
this.$refs.address.$refs.autocomplete.value = '';
```

Add this in your input ref vue-google-autocomplete

```
ref="autocomplete"
```

Comment: if you focus field again, then value appear again